# Getting errors that i do not understand C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hello_World
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string string1 = "Hello";
            Console.WriteLine(string1);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
namespace Numbers_And_Stuff
{
    class Programming
    {
       int numbers = (int) 53.23f;
       Console.WriteLine(numbers);
    }
}
```

Im getting these errors -

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1519  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>   that applies to ')' As well
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'Console.WriteLine' does not exist in the current context.
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'numbers' does not exist in the current context.
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'WriteLine' does not exist in the current context.

Thanks!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(numbers);` has to be in a method, not at the class level.

Answer (score 5):

Executable code need to to be inside of functions, the `Console.WriteLine(numbers);` is not inside any function it is in the class level.